# How can I optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here's the query:

```
SELECT p.name p_name,
c.name c_name,
p.line1,
p.zip,
c.line1,
p.zip
FROM

(SELECT c.name,
ad.line1,
ad.zip
FROM customer c
JOIN account a ON a.customer_id = c.id
JOIN account_address aa ON aa.account_id = a.id
JOIN address ad ON aa.address_id = ad.id
JOIN account_import ai ON a.account_import_id = ai.id
JOIN generic_import gi ON ai.generic_import_id = gi.id
JOIN import_bundle ib ON gi.import_bundle_id = ib.id
WHERE gi.active = 1
AND ib.active = 1
AND ib.bank_id = 8
LIMIT 1000) c

JOIN
(SELECT p.name,
a.line1,
a.zip
FROM prospect p
JOIN address a ON p.address_id = a.id) p
ON
0
OR (p.zip = c.zip AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 12) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 12))
OR (p.zip = c.zip AND p.name = c.name)
OR (p.zip = c.zip
  AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 4)
  AND SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name, ' ', -1), 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.name, ' ', -1), 1, 4))
OR (p.zip = c.zip
  AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 3) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 3)
  AND SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name, ' ', -1), 1, 3) = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.name, ' ', -1), 1, 3)
  AND SUBSTRING(p.line1, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(c.line1, 1, 4))
```

Here's the `EXPLAIN`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1000
        Extra:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived3>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 15030
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: p
         type: ALL
possible_keys: address_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 15067
        Extra:
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: a
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_address_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: mcif.p.address_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: ib
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: PRIMARY,bank_id,fk_bank_id,index_import_bundle_id,index_import_bundle_bank_id,index_import_bundle_active
          key: index_import_bundle_active,fk_bank_id
      key_len: 1,8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using intersect(index_import_bundle_active,fk_bank_id); Using where; Using index
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: gi
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,import_bundle_id,index_generic_import_id,index_generic_import_import_bundle_id,index_generic_import_active
          key: import_bundle_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: mcif.ib.id
         rows: 34
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: ai
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,generic_import_id,index_account_import_generic_import_id
          key: generic_import_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: mcif.gi.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 8. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: a
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_account_customer_id,index_account_customer_id,index_account_id,index_account_account_import_id
          key: index_account_account_import_id
      key_len: 9
          ref: mcif.ai.id
         rows: 1482
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 9. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: c
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_customer_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: mcif.a.customer_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 10. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: aa
         type: ref
possible_keys: fk_account_address_account_id,fk_account_address_address_id,index_account_address_account_id,index_account_address_address_id
          key: fk_account_address_account_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: mcif.a.id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 11. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: ad
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_address_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: mcif.aa.address_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
11 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

I have no idea where to begin. I think mostly I just need someone to explain the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: That is one ugly query if I ever saw one. Focus on trying to remove the sub selects and replacing them by pure joins instead.

Comment: Jonas, your comment was the most helpful in my rewriting of the query. If you say the same thing as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to take out the subqueries and rewrite the query using only joins.

Answer (score 1):

Those substrings are ruining any chance you have of using an index, can you remove them and join on full names?  If not, can you add an extra, indexed column to your tables that contain the name substrings, then join on those?

Answer (score 0):

the database engine will try to remove lines using the `where` clauses as soon as possible. however, in your first sub-select, it's not possible to start using the `where` clauses to remove lines until you've joined the tables 6 tables. the first table you refer to in the `where` clauses should always be the first table you select from, and the second table you refer to in the `where` clauses should be the first table you join in.

so try switching the order of the tables in the big inner select :)

here's my attempt, but of course untested since i don't have the database:

```
SELECT
  p.name AS p_name,
  c.name AS c_name,
  p.line1,
  p.zip,
  c.line1,
  p.zip
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.name,
    ad.line1,
    ad.zip
  FROM generic_import AS gi
  JOIN import_bundle AS ib ON gi.import_bundle_id = ib.id
  JOIN account_import AS ai ON ai.generic_import_id = gi.id
  JOIN account AS a ON a.account_import_id = ai.id
  JOIN account_address AS aa ON aa.account_id = a.id
  JOIN address AS ad ON aa.address_id = ad.id
  JOIN customer AS c ON a.customer_id = c.id
  WHERE gi.active = 1
    AND ib.active = 1
    AND ib.bank_id = 8
  LIMIT 1000) AS c
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      p.name,
      a.line1,
      a.zip
    FROM prospect AS p
    JOIN address AS a ON p.address_id = a.id
    ) AS p
    ON (p.zip = c.zip
    AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 12) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 12)
       )
    OR (p.zip = c.zip AND p.name = c.name)
    OR 
    (p.zip = c.zip AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 4)
      AND SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name, ' ', -1), 1, 4) = 
        SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.name, ' ', -1), 1, 4)
    )
    OR 
    (p.zip = c.zip AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 3) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 3)
    AND SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name, ' ', -1), 1, 3) = 
      SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.name, ' ', -1), 1, 3)
    AND SUBSTRING(p.line1, 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(c.line1, 1, 4)
    )
```

was it faster? D:

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `prospect.name` to the index on `prospect.address_id`, so you will have an index on `address_id,name` instead. It should improve performance a bit (at least row 3 from `explain`). 
Also line
`OR (p.zip = c.zip AND p.name = c.name)` seems to be superfluous -
 `(p.zip = c.zip AND SUBSTRING(p.name, 1, 12) = SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 12))` includes all rows where `p.name = c.name`.